# Best strategy for building Redshift Data Warehouse from multiple DBs

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-redshift, etl

I need some guidance on our strategy for loading data into a Redshift Data Warehouse for analytics. We have ~40 SQL databases, each represents one customer and each database is identical. I have a SQL database with the same table structure as the 40 but each table has an additional column called "customer" that will capture where that record came from. We do some additional ETL processing with the records as they come in.

In total we have about 50 GB of data across all 40 DBs. Looking into the recommended processes for Updating / Inserting data on [AWS's site](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/merge-replacing-existing-rows.html) they recommend creating the scratch table then merging data.  I could do this but I could also just drop all the data from a table and re-load it since I am reading from the source every time. What is the recommended way to handle this?

Comment: what is your source rdbms? is it on rds? how many tables per customer?

Comment: Source is MySQL, it is not on RDS. There are ~59 tables per customer.